# Regex expression to match semicolons inside nested parentheses

Tags: php, regex, matching, regex-group, brackets

I need a Regex expression to match semicolons inside nested parentheses.

For example, in the line

```
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {
```

I need to match only both semicolons followed by **3** and **)**

Currently I'm doing this by using the expression `/;(?=((?!\(\().)*?\))/`

But when using above expression in the line below,

```
int rows = 5; for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i){
```

the semicolon followed by **5** also matched.

I need only to match semicolons inside brackets.

That would be a great help if anyone can suggest me a regular expression that can overcome both of these situations.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTQdL.png)

Comment: it's hard to use regex to parse code. You need consider many cases. Ex: open bracket and close bracket in multi-line; nested bracket.

Comment: Do you want to replace them with another text? Also, should they only be matched if there is `for` word before the parentheses?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I need to replace them with Greek Question Mark (;). It looks like semicolon but its not. Actually in my program I need to split a java code snippet into lines. By using {, ;, } characters. So I don't want a given java code snippet to be split into a new line because of a semicolon inside "for", "while" loop's brackets. So when I replaced the semicolons inside them as Greek question mark (;) those are not considered as semicolons. Hope you will understand my point. Cheers.

Comment: I mean to say that it is not a regex job to parse or manipulate source code. There are refactoring tools for that. You may try something like https://3v4l.org/Homiok, but this might turn out too specific for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As a newbie I'm so glad for the things you pointed out to me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get all the matches of `for` or `while` followed with a balanced amount of parentheses after them, and then replace the semicolons only inside the matches with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
'~\b(?:while|for)\s*(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WYTDWo/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:while|for)` - `while` or `for` words
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1 (its pattern will be recursed with `(?1)`):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - 0 or more occurrences of any 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 pattern
- `\)` - a `)` char

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Homiok):

```
$s = "for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {";
echo preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:while|for)\s*(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))~u', function($m) {
    return str_replace(';', ';', $m[0]); },
$s);
```

Output:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2) {
```

Comment: For those who did not read the comments below the question: inside `str_replace`, we replace a regular ASCII `;` with the Greek question mark, `;`. See the [chars description](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%3B%CD%BE).